# Is it dangerous to allow users to add javascript code in a page that's supposed to be viewed outside my app?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, security, xss

I have a Ruby on rails web application that helps users to create their portfolio. Initially they choose a template and they have the ability to change the text of the chosen template. here I provide them with a specific fields like `"headline"`, "`description"`, `"projects"`... these fields are validated server side to not permit `html` code.

I have two other fields:

1. embed video code (from youtube, vimeo etc...)
2. Another field which allow addition of custom JavaScript.(maybe they want to add a popup script, or a tracking code or whatever).

When they finish editing the template, they click "publish" button and their portfolio can be seen on their sub-domain which is based on my app domain ex: `user-subdomain.myapp.com/portfolio`

My question is : can allowing users to put in custom JavaScript or embeding video code affect the security of my application?  Am I vulnerable to XSS, Hijacking, or hacking? If I am, how do I fix those issues using Rails?

Comment: *"it's not supposed to be viewed by others member of my site, in fact they should promote their portfolio which is something like `user-subdomain.myapp.com/portfolio` in the internet"* Huh? That's the URL you said it would be used on. Presumably others will see it?

Comment: Voting to close as too broad because this question is both "unclear" (in that the comments above point out you're sending us contradicting statements), and "If it's a security problem, I'll be thankful if you can give me some advices...".  We need to see some sample code; specifically, code that creates that new page; what are you using on the server? Are you using any validation/whitelisting/filtering at all? If so, what are you using; if not, what is the range of acceptable things they could put on their page? WE'd need a complete list; as well as information about your storage and stack.

Answer (score 1):

If they are entering JavaScript code which you will then store and include when showing a page to **other** users, then yes, it's a security hole. It means that they can do anything you can do on that page, in the context of someone else's user account; this could be used to steal information from other users, etc.

If only **they** will ever view the page with the embedded JavaScript, no, it doesn't make your page less secure; they coudl easily inject JavaScript into your page via bookmarklets or even just using the console.

Comment: Can you explain the last part please?

Comment: @imreal: If you're only putting the code on pages that run for **that** user, then it's not less secure because that user can always open up the web console while you're page is showing and execute arbitrary JavaScript. So you providing them a means to do that isn't making the page less secure. It's only when you let them give you code that you'll run in **other** users' browsers that you're making things less secure (for your other users).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder in my example above, users of my app will not know about the subdomain link of the "evil" user, because each user will create his specific subdomain which is different than other, the only case is that maybe one user is opening his account in my app and by chance he find the link of "evil" user in the internet and open it ! what do you think ?

Comment: @medBo: If the user isn't meant to see the page, don't let them see the page. Security through obscurity is no security at all.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder humm I just thought of it as a low-risk as it can only be happen by coincidence...  I have no way to prevent the user from seeing the page if he find it by chance on google...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder but I think if a "good" user is opening his account on "clients.myapp.com" and he open the page of "evil" user which is "evil-subdomain.myapp.com" then there is no security issue ? right ?

Comment: @medBo: Wrong. The evil user's code runs on the page in the context of the good user's browser and (if relevant) login to your site. Very Bad Thing.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I found answers and blogposts that says subdomains prevent xss issue !! I am totally lost

Comment: @medBo: They don't if you let any user access them. Please engage the services of a professional or do a **lot** more study before you let users loose on this thing.